# Best practice for validating a date in url in django?

Tags: django

I have a logging system, where users can log several symptoms for any given day. Im getting the date as slug in my url, but I need to validate it. Which one is best practice, and why?

1. make a validator function in the class view and use it there
2. add a hidden form field, and write a custom DateValidator for it?

Comment: A date as slug? I would really advise to use a new path pattern that works with a date.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you mean <int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a path converter that will parse `date` objects. You can define a custom pattern with:

```
# app_name/converters.py

class DateConverter:
    regex = '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
    format = '%Y-%m-%d'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.strptime(value, self.format).date()

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value.strftime(self.format)
```

Next we can [register that path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) and work with:

```
from app_name.converters import DateConverter
from django.urls import path, register_converter

register_converter(DateConverter, 'date')

urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('some/path/<date:date>/', some_view),
    # …
]
```

This will pass a single `date` parameter to the view, which is a `date` object, you thus can work with:

```
def some_view(request, date):
    # …
```

If you thus visit the path `/some/path/2021-10-17`, `date` will be a `date(2021, 10, 17)` object.

Comment: Oh, this is perfect! thanks. What if I wanted to do an extra validation, like the date being in a specific range? where is the best place for that?

Comment: @eva: you can do that in the view, and in case it is outside the range for example use `raise Http404`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception